# Cross Validation Using libsvm

Tags: matlab, libsvm

I am currently performing 5 - fold cross validation where I am using this code :

```
%# read some training data
[labels,data] = libsvmread('Training_Data_libsvmFormat.txt');

%# grid of parameters
folds = 5; 
[C,gamma] = meshgrid(-5:2:15, -15:2:3)  %Coarse Grid Search: bestC = 8 bestGamma = 2
%[C,gamma] = meshgrid(1:0.5:4, -1:0.25:3) %Fine Grid Search: bestC = 4 bestGamma = 2

%# grid search, and cross-validation
cv_acc = zeros(numel(C),1);
for i=1:numel(C)
    cv_acc(i) = svmtrain(labels, data, sprintf('-c %f -g %f -v %d', 2^C(i), 2^gamma(i), folds));
end

%# pair (C,gamma) with best accuracy
[~,idx] = max(cv_acc);

%# contour plot of paramter selection
contour(C, gamma, reshape(cv_acc,size(C))), colorbar
hold on
plot(C(idx), gamma(idx), 'rx')
text(C(idx), gamma(idx), sprintf('Acc = %.2f %%',cv_acc(idx)), 'HorizontalAlign','left', 'VerticalAlign','top')
hold off
xlabel('log_2(C)'), ylabel('log_2(\gamma)'), title('Cross-Validation Accuracy')

%# now you can train you model using best_C and best_gamma
best_C = 2^C(idx);
best_gamma = 2^gamma(idx);
```

Now, I know that in 5 fold cross validation, 4/5 of dataset are used for training and 1/5 for testing and all the time changing the testing part to obtain the best cross C and gamma for RBF. However, in the dataset the 1st 1000 examples are positive while the last 3000 are all negative. Does cross validation using svmtrain() shuffle the data or it may be the case that the 1/5 for testing contains all negative examples please? I am asking this question as if it does not shuffle the data, the accuracy is not realistic.

I appreciate you assistance.

Comment: What do you mean by "1st 1000" and "last 3000"? Afaics, the documentation doesn't say anything definitive about how data are partitioned for cross-validation. If you want to be sure, you could shuffle the data yourself, using e.g. `randperm`.

Comment: OK, let me rephrase that. I have 4000 training images ..the 1st 1000 are +ve examples and the rest are negative. OK so I will try and shuffle them tnx :)